# Datatables not sorting date correctly Serverside

Tags: mysql, sorting, datatables-1.10

I am using server side processing, so as I understand, all sorting/ordering is done server side. However, when I click on the column header, it should send the server a post variable to apply the ASC or DESC sort order. This is not working and I'm trying to figure out where my problem lies.

I am using the default script that comes with datatables.

My dates in the database is stored as timestamp values such as 15-10-2015 10:20:30.

Now, the table displays fine, however the dates are not sorted correctly. Even if I output just the year values e.g. 2014 , it does not sort them ASC and DESC.

Instead, I get results like:

2014
2014
2015
2015
2014
2014
2015

:(

I declare the table as follows :

```
DemoTable = $('#table_demo').DataTable(
            {
                "order": [],
                "aaSorting" : [],
                "deferRender": true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bStateSave": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "ajax":
                {
                    "url": "view_demo_remote.php",
                    "data":
                    {
                        "role": $_SESSION['role'],
                        "email": $_SESSION['email'],
                        "practiseid": $_SESSION['practiceid']
                    }
                },
                "columns":[
                    { "data": "first_number" , "bSortable": true },
                    { "data": "datecreated", "bSortable": true },
                    { "data": "submitted_by"},
                    { "data": "second_number"},
                    { "data": "picture","bSortable": false  },
                    { "data": "options","bSortable": false }
                ],
});
```

On the server, I have the following section for the columns:

```
$columns = array(
            array(
                'db' => 'id',
                'dt' => 'DT_RowId',
                'formatter' => function( $d, $row )
                {
                    // Technically a DOM id cannot start with an integer, so we prefix
                    // a string. This can also be useful if you have multiple tables
                    // to ensure that the id is unique with a different prefix
                    return $d;
                }
            ),
            array(
                'db'        => 'firstnumber',
                'dt'        => 'first_number',
                'formatter' => function($d, $row)
                {
                    $number = $d;
                    return substr($number, 0, 10);
                }),
            array(
                'db'        => 'datecreated',
                'dt'        => 'datecreated',
                'formatter' => function($d, $row)
                {
                    // DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS
                    $date = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y H:i:s', $d);
                    return date_format($date, 'Y');
                }),
            array( 'db' => 'username',   'dt' => 'submitted_by' ),
            array( 'db' => 'secondnumber',   'dt' => 'second_number' ),
            array(
                'db'        => 'picture',
                'dt'        => 'picture',
                'formatter' => function($d, $row)
                {
                    return "<p style=\"padding:5px;\"><img src=\"".$d."\" alt=\"Picture\" style=\"width:auto;max-height:70px;border:1px solid #2d2d2d;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;  \"></img></p>";
                }),
            array( 'db'        => 'id', 'dt'        => 'options');
            );
```

and then I have this part after the columns section:

```
// SQL server connection information
        $sql_details = array(
                'user' => DBUSER,
                'pass' => DBUSERPASS,
                'db'   => DBNAME,
                'host' => DBHOST
        );


        require( 'libraries/DataTables-1.10.7/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );

        $whereAll = " firstnumber <>''";
        echo json_encode(SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, "",$whereAll));
```

So the table displays fine, all column headers for the sortable columns can be clicked on and it sorts ASC or DESC perfectly. However, the date does not sort perfectly. If I turn off sorting off on the table and I manually add "ORDER BY datecreated ASC" to the where clause, it works perfectly, which tells me that there is nothing wrong with my date format, however, I want sorting ON.

Please help

I have also asked a question on the datatables forums https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/31216/datatables-not-ordering-date-correctly

Comment: Nope, datatable sort data on the client side. In this particular case, as text. This is why you get the wrong order.

Comment: According to the documentation, it reads "With server-side processing enabled, all paging, searching, ordering actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server" https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: @Shadow but yes, I get what you are saying. I have tried to apply client side formatting with the render function, but this did the same thing. It changed the format but still did not sort correctly.

Comment: @Shadow -  No, `"serverSide": true` does exactly what it suggests : Hands over sorting to the serverside script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for contributing.

At the end of the day, the problem was actually caused by a field in the database that was in the wrong format. The datecreated field was saved as a Varchar and it had to be DATETIME.

Once I fixed this in the database, everything sorted perfectly.

thanks for everyone who helped. But yes, I want to stress the fact that when server side processing is being done, all sorting / ordering is done server side. You can manipulate the format and display on the client side, but NOT the actual order, when server side is being used.